# Getting back a specific type for a relationship when using inheritance?

Tags: database-design, sqlalchemy

What I have so far is the following tables:

```
|nodes| |types| |persons| |images|
```

Where `|persons|` and `|images|` are `|types|` and `|nodes|` has `|types|`.

I'm trying to represent the database schema I have so far using SQLAlchemy's declarative syntax so I can easily query the database from Python. The problem however is that when I query node.types I'm getting back the generic `Type` class instead of the specific `Person` (or whatever) class.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'nodes'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    types = relationship("Type")

class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'types'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    node_id = Column("node_id", Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))

class Person(Type):
    __tablename__ = "persons"
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': '/people/person'}

    id = Column("id", Integer, ForeignKey('types.id'), primary_key=True)
```

Example:

```
session = Session()
print session.query(Node).one().types[0]
... <__main__.Type object at 0x9a4decc>
```

How can I easily get the specific type instead of the generic type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind. I forgot to add `polymorphic_on` to the `Type` class. That is:

```
class Type(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'types'
    __table_args__ = {'autoload': True}

    type = Column("type", String)
    node_id = Column("node_id", Integer, ForeignKey('nodes.id'))

    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_on': type}
```